# quickfix vs fix antenna

Tags: quickfix

There are two major fix engines:

- opensource QuickFix http://www.quickfixengine.org/
- commercial Fix Antenna http://www.b2bits.com/trading_solutions/fix_engines/fix_engine_cpp.html

What are cons and prons of each of them? I know that Fix Antenna is faster, but what else?

Is QuickFix project alive. Changelog shows that last commit to QuickFix was at 2010-04-06 06:22, does it mean that project is dead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As DumbCoder says, there are a lot more than 2 major FIX engines.  Cameron tends to be used by a number of investment banks.  Rapid Addition also have a highly regarded FIX engine - and there are lots more.  QuickFix is very popular and is relied on and used by lots of individuals and trading businesses and can be an excellent choice unless you are very latency sensitive.

There is always also the option to write your own.  It depends on your use case.  If you aren't hugely latency sensitive (care about microseconds), then QuickFix is probably your best bet.  Otherwise, if you do care about every microsecond and want more predictable latency per message processed, then QuickFix will not work for you and you either want a low latency commerical solution (such as Rapid Addition Cheetah) or you want to write your own which is optimised to your usage scenario.  Note that writing your own to beat the performance of a commercial solution will take some time and is no easy feat as many of the commercial engines are now highly performant.

Answer (score 3):

Having undertaken extensive benchmarking for QuickFix, Antenna, Onix, Rapid Addition and Cameron we have opted for Onix . www.onixs.biz.

We benchmarked Java, C++ and .net solutions and have gone live with C++ on RHEL5.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the performance test code included in QuickFix C++ and got the results below. As far as I can tell, this looks excellent. And I am running a commodity home desktop not a high-end trading server used by big shops. The build was done with VS 2012 at full optimization.

G:\projects\quickfix\test\release\pt>pt.exe -p 15000 -c 1000000

Converting integers to strings:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 0.016, num_per_second: 6.25e+007
```

Converting strings to integers:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 0, num_per_second: 1.#INF
```

Converting doubles to strings:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 0.5, num_per_second: 2e+006
```

Converting strings to doubles:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 0.219, num_per_second: 4.56621e+006
```

Creating Heartbeat messages:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 0.75, num_per_second: 1.33333e+006
```

Identifying message types:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 0.062, num_per_second: 1.6129e+007
```

Serializing Heartbeat messages to strings:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 0.516, num_per_second: 1.93798e+006
```

Serializing Heartbeat messages from strings:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 1.094, num_per_second: 914077
```

Creating NewOrderSingle messages:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 2.312, num_per_second: 432526
```

Serializing NewOrderSingle messages to strings:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 0.75, num_per_second: 1.33333e+006
```

Serializing NewOrderSingle messages from strings:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 3.188, num_per_second: 313676
```

Creating QuoteRequest messages:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 41.547, num_per_second: 24069.1
```

Serializing QuoteRequest messages to strings:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 3.734, num_per_second: 267809
```

Serializing QuoteRequest messages from strings:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 26.672, num_per_second: 37492.5
```

Reading fields from QuoteRequest message:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 15.89, num_per_second: 62932.7
```

Storing NewOrderSingle messages:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 3.485, num_per_second: 286944
```

Validating NewOrderSingle messages with no data dictionary:

```
num: 1000000, seconds: 0.11, num_per_second: 9.09091e+006
```

Validating NewOrderSingle messages with data dictionary:

G:\projects\quickfix\test\release\pt>

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily the 2 major FIX engines. Cameron is another widely used FIX engine. Many financial companies do develop their own FIX engines. There isn't a list of pros and cons for the FIX engines, per se as most of them aren't built the same way and other factors creep in during development. Only way is evaluate them yourselves for your specific needs.

Quickfix project is pretty much alive. There do exist some commercial companies which provide support for Quickfix, it is probably there on the Quickfix website. And you do have the source code, there is nothing stopping you from tinkering yourself.

Comment: if QuickFix is alive then where I can check versions history? How much perfomance was improved in last 2 years? Why quickfix perfomance can not be as good as fix antenna perfomance?

Comment: @javapowered - Where did you get the metrics for your test results ? For what data transfer were the engines used for ? Is it just you thought or assumptions ? What performance are you talking about ? Trading or something else ? Check the quickfix website and the sourceforge websites for version details. I mentioned to check out the commercial companies which provide support for Quickfix, did you try that out ?

Comment: i talked to people and they say that quickfix is slower, also look at this results: http://www.b2bits.com/performance_lab/fast_antenna_codec/fast_codec_windows.html I didn't tried commercial companies. I can't find versions history on quickfix website.